# onItemClick on ViewPager2's nested GridView not registering

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I'm using ViewPager2 to put together a calendar, where each ViewPager2's view represents a month, and each nested GridView represents the days in a month. The ViewPager2 is set with an offscreenPageLimit of 1.

The following occurs in ViewPager2's RecyclerView adapter according to the pages selected:

- Starting at page 0: onBindViewHolder and onViewAttached are called for pages 0 and 1.
- From page 0 to page 1: onBindViewHolder is called for pages 2 and 3. onViewAttached is called for page 2.
- From page 1 to page 2: onBindViewHolder is called for page 4. onViewAttached is called for page 3.
- From page 2 to page 3: onBindViewHolder is called for page 5. onViewAttached is called for page 4.
- From page 3 back to page 2: onBindViewHolder is not called. onViewAttached is called for page 1.
- **From page 2 back to page 1: onBindViewHolder is not called. onViewAttached is called for page 0. The nested GridView's onItemClick is not responsive here.**

The following 2 scenarios enable the GridView's onItemClick to be responsive in this case:

- Slight scroll to either side and staying on page 1. (I'm guessing the ViewPager's scrollstate is changed and something is refreshed.)
- Going from page 1 to page 2, and then back to page 1.

ViewPager RecyclerView Adapter:

```
class CalendarVPAdapter(private val allDates: ArrayList<ArrayList<LocalDate>>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<CalendarVPAdapter.ViewPagerViewHolder>() {

    private var eventDates = ArrayList<LocalDate>()
    private var selectedDate: LocalDate = Clock.System.todayAt(TimeZone.currentSystemDefault())
    private var selectedView: View? = null
    private var dateList = ArrayList<LocalDate>()
    var listener: ((LocalDate)->Unit)? = null


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewPagerViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_calendar_view_pager, parent, false)

        return ViewPagerViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewPagerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        dateList = allDates[position]

        val gridAdapter = CalendarGridAdapter(dateList, eventDates, selectedDate)

        holder.gridView.adapter = gridAdapter

        holder.gridView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            Log.d("VPAdapter onItemClick", "${gridAdapter.getItem(position)}")
            Log.d("VPAdapter onItemClick", "${holder.layoutPosition} ${holder.gridView.onItemClickListener}")
        }

        Log.d("VPAdapter onBind", "${holder.layoutPosition} ${holder.gridView.onItemClickListener}")

    }

    override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: ViewPagerViewHolder) {
        Log.d("VPAdapter onViewAttached", holder.layoutPosition.toString() + " " + holder.gridView.onItemClickListener.toString())
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = allDates.size

    class ViewPagerViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val gridView: GridView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pagerGrid)
    }
}
```

In short, I'm unsure why the nested GridView's onItemClick is unresponsive in some specific scenarios. Appreciate any insights or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewPagerViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_calendar_view_pager, parent, false)
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        return ViewPagerViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this but the issue still persists. Setting the onClickListener in onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder or onViewAttachedToWindow doesn't quite help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out something but I'm not certain on the specific problem. The ViewPagerAdapter was prefetching views, thus it was creating and binding 2 views before and after the current view. In the example above, at Page 3, the adapter had already binded Page 1, but navigating back resulted in Page 1 reattaching, but not rebinding.

The following lines helped to overcome this issue:

```
        viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 1
        (viewPager.getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView).layoutManager?.isItemPrefetchEnabled = false
        (viewPager.getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView).setItemViewCacheSize(0)
```